# When do we use the react custom hooks and react context?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

#### Some points I figured out of React context

- Methods and states shared to child components from the parent by Provider component

#### Some points I figured out of React custom hooks

- It is also used to share the methods and states to any function component

1. I really obfuscated with the use cases of React context and Custom hooks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

1.custom hooks :
When you wanna to share logic between two JavaScript functions, you can extract it into a third function.we know that Both components and Hooks are functions, so this works for them too!
A custom Hook is a JavaScript function that starts with ”use” and that can call other Hooks. For example, "useCheckStatus";
There’s nothing new about it!

2.Context :
in real project our states grows fast and we have a bunch of those.
so we should manage them, we have different ways to solve that
one of them is Context
that is so good for medium projects

in huge projects we use Redux.

hopefully my answer can clear subject for you.

Answer (score -1):

**React Custom Hooks** enable you to share stateful logic not only the state. Check more about [writing custom react hooks](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks)

**React Context and its APIs** can be used to share a state that you want to access anywhere in the children component without passing it down in the children's hierarchy. In some projects, developers use advanced state-management tools such as [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/), [Zustand](https://zustand-demo.pmnd.rs/), [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/) etc.
Refer to this guide on [react.dev](https://react.dev/reference/react/createContext)